# if-statement in R: "missing value" error despite existing value

Tags: r, if-statement

An if-statement returns an "missing Value"-error when there is a perfectly healthy value.

I wanted to write a simple script to delete rows in a dataset if one of their entries contains a certain tag. I assign an indicator variable in a new column (containsMR) and then iterate over the rows using a for-loop. If the indicator is TRUE, the row should be removed.

The indicators get assigned correctly, so far, so good. The interesting part: In the loop's if-statement seems to have trouble reading the values, because it returns "Error in if (data$containsMR[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".

Given the correct (and complete) assignment of indicator variables, this surprises me. What is even more weird: Some, but not all the rows with a positive indicator are removed (checked with printouts and table(data$containsMR) ).

And now the really weird stuff: if I run the same loop one more time, it removes the rest of the columns (as it should), but returns the same error. So, theoretically, I could just run the loop twice, ignore the errors and walk away with the result I wanted. That's just really not the point of what I'm doing.

Bugfixes tried:
- changed for- to while-loop
- changed indicators (and if-statement) to integer (0,1)
- ran the script in RStudio and R console
- changed variable names, included/excluded definitions (e.g. adding the proxy variable row_number instead of calling it in one line.

```
# Script to delete all rows containing "MR" in column "EXAM_CODE"

# import file
data <- read.csv("C:\\ScriptingTest\\ablations 0114.csv")

# add indicator column
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    data$containsMR[i] <- ifelse(grepl("MR", toString(data$EXAM_CODE[i])), TRUE, FALSE)
}

# remove rows with positive indicator
row_number <- nrow(data)
for (i in 1:row_number){
    if (data$containsMR[i]){
        data <- data[-c(i),]
    }
}

# export csv
write.csv(data, "C:\\ScriptingTest\\export.csv")
```

Comment: Think about this for a second: you're changing the number of rows in `data` during the loop, but the length of the loop is fixed. What happens when `data` has 100 rows, but your for loop still needs to get up to 105?

Comment: Also, you could do this in one line, e.g. `data[data$containsMR > 0,]`.

Comment: ... or I guess `data[!data$containsMR,]` since that's actually boolean.

Comment: Deleting and indexing is not a problem (to my knowledge); deleting line 3 will result in the lines being 1;2;4;[…]

Comment: It is definitely a problem. You will eventually be indexing a row that no longer exists because you've run off the end of the data frame.

Comment: @petemq The labeled row numbers will not change when you delete rows (you will get `1;2;4;`, as you say above), but you never actually use those row numbers when you index. If `d <- data.frame(x = 5:8, y = 'a')`, and then do `d <- d[-3]`, the row numbers will still be `1,2,4`, but `d[4, ]` will return and data frame of `NA`.

Comment: One other minor tip: pretty much any time you have `ifelse(<something>, TRUE, FALSE)`, the `ifelse` isn't necessary. `<something> is giving `ifelse()` a TRUE or a FALSE, and you don't need `ifelse` to convert it on to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You can just use `<something>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to simplify this to

```
newdata <-  data[!grepl("MR", data$EXAM_CODE),]
```

Comment: That works and is a lot more elegant than my code. Thanks!
Up until now I only used R for statistical analysis, but I guess I should catch up on basic principles.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the problem is modifying the size of the object in the for loop that you are looping over, see this example:

```
n <- nrow(mtcars)

for (i in 1:n){
  cat("\n mtcars currently has",nrow(mtcars),"rows;","accessing row",i)
  if (mtcars$cyl[i] == 4){
    mtcars <- mtcars[-i,]
  }
}

> mtcars currently has 32 rows; accessing row 1
 mtcars currently has 32 rows; accessing row 2
 mtcars currently has 32 rows; accessing row 3
 mtcars currently has 31 rows; accessing row 4
 mtcars currently has 31 rows; accessing row 5
 mtcars currently has 31 rows; accessing row 6
 mtcars currently has 31 rows; accessing row 7
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 8
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 9
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 10
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 11
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 12
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 13
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 14
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 15
 mtcars currently has 30 rows; accessing row 16
 mtcars currently has 29 rows; accessing row 17
 mtcars currently has 28 rows; accessing row 18
 mtcars currently has 28 rows; accessing row 19
 mtcars currently has 28 rows; accessing row 20
 mtcars currently has 28 rows; accessing row 21
 mtcars currently has 28 rows; accessing row 22
 mtcars currently has 27 rows; accessing row 23
 mtcars currently has 26 rows; accessing row 24
 mtcars currently has 26 rows; accessing row 25
 mtcars currently has 26 rows; accessing row 26
 mtcars currently has 25 rows; accessing row 27
Error in if (mtcars$cyl[i] == 4) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I guess this explains the issue I was having before